# How does Autosave in Mac OS X Lion 10.7 work? How can I change the autosave frequency?

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-lion

Just curious if anyone has some insight into how Autosave works in Lion? For Applications that have been optimized to take advantage of the Autosave API's - is there a frequency with which the document is "auto saved"? can it be manipulated? where is the autosave data stored? Any insight or details would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could also try a search on "apple.stackexchange.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lion's Autosave is different from previous versions of autosaving in that it saves directly to the user's file (instead of, for example, a "My Document (Autosaved)" file to the side).

Autosaving happens for a multitude of reasons, only one of which is periodic autosaving. You can influence the autosaving frequency by overriding NSDocumentController's `-autosavingDelay` method, but this is mostly just used as a hint on Lion, not a hard requirement.

If you really want to, you can also override NSDocument's `-scheduleAutosaving`, but NSDocument has a lot of smarts in that method that you may not override.

There is also the concept of "implicitly cancelable" autosaves, which you can use to cancel a periodic autosave if you think now isn't a good time, for whatever reason.

The Lion AppKit release notes have a lot more info that you'll find useful.

Comment: Great information! Thank you.